# Numpy: Column dependent slicing

Tags: python, numpy

I could not find any question concerning what I want to do so I am asking now. Basically, I want slicing in matrices where the row index depends on the column index.

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(24).reshape(6,4)
>>> x
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

Now what I need is:

```
array([[12,  9,  6,  3],
       [16, 13, 10,  7],
       [20, 17, 14, 11]])
```

So I have a given (fixed) set of column indices. The row indices depend on them. For example: `row = col-1:col+1`

Is there an efficient way to do that? I know I can iterate and slice the entries I need from every single column, but it seems very inefficient to me.

Comment: You can build this up out of a combination of `np.diag` and `np.rot90` and maybe `np.transpose`. Leaving this as a comment because I don't see how to do the exact extraction you ask for.

Comment: A diagonal solution: `np.array([x[::-1,:].diagonal(i) for i in [-2,-1,0]])`.  It does involve interation over each row of the output since `np.diagonal` does not takes a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `as_strided` to do this:

```
In [1]: from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
In [2]: sz = x.itemsize
In [3]: d = as_strided(x[-1::-1,:], shape=(3,4), strides=sz*np.array([-4,-3]))
In [4]: d
Out[5]: 
array([[20, 17, 14, 11],
       [16, 13, 10,  7],
       [12,  9,  6,  3]])
```

That is, starting with the original array upside-down, fill a 3x4 array with items taken by striding backwards 4 items for the first coordinate and 3 for the second.

If you want, you can then view `d` upside-down:

```
In [6]: d[-1::-1,:]    # or np.flipud(d)
Out[6]: 
array([[12,  9,  6,  3],
       [16, 13, 10,  7],
       [20, 17, 14, 11]])
```

Answer (score 2):

I was going to leave a `diagonal` based solution in the comments, but in time tests it proves to be faster than the `strided` one.

```
In [128]: timeit d = as_strided(x[::-1,:], shape=(3,4),
     strides=sz*np.array([-4,-3]))[::-1,:]
10000 loops, best of 3: 44 µs per loop

In [129]: timeit np.array([x[::-1,:].diagonal(i) for i in [-2,-1,0]])
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.9 µs per loop
```

With a larger `x` this probably will not be true.  But the `diagonal` solution has the advantage that it might be easier to understand.

---

for a `(69,40)` `x`,

```
np.array([x[::-1,:].diagonal(i) for i in range(-(n-1),1)])
```

produces a `(30,40)` array that includes all of the length 40 reverse diagonals.

The `as_strided` solution is:

```
as_strided(x[::-1,:], shape=(n,m), strides=-sz*np.array([m,m-1]))[::-1,:]
```

It wasn't as easy to figure out how to adjust the values to produce the correct strides.  But it is faster.  Time basically the same as for the smaller array, while the `diagonal` approach slows down with size.